# AWS CLI - 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 26

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-route53

I have a large number of route53 records that I have to move and am following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-migrating.html

I have created the txt file and have updated it, but when I run the command, I get the following error

```
PS C:\> aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZNEWZONE1245 --profile new_account --change-batch file://list-records-ZNEWZONE1245.json

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xff' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

here is the contant for `list-records-ZNEWZONE1245.json`

```
{
    "Comment": "Import domain.tld route53 sets",
    "Changes": [
        {
            "Action": "CREATE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "192.0.2.4"
                    }
                ], 
                "Type": "A", 
                "Name": "domain.tld.", 
                "TTL": 300
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": "CREATE",
            "ResourceRecordSet":{
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "5 ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Value": "1 ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Value": "10 ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Value": "10 ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"
                    }, 
                    {
                        "Value": "5 ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM"
                    }
                ], 
            "Type": "MX", 
            "Name": "domain.tld.", 
            "TTL": 300
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

Any advise is much appreciated.

Comment: Does your domain name (`domain.tld` in your example above) contain non-ascii characters?  That's about position 26.

Comment: no it does not, i created a python script and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the encoding on the json file to ANSI.

1. Open list-records-ZNEWZONE1245.json on a text editor (I use Notepad++)
2. **Change the file encoding from UTF to ANSI**
3. Save the file.

**Re-run your AWS CLI command**:

```
PS C:\> aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id ZNEWZONE1245 --profile new_account --change-batch file://list-records-ZNEWZONE1245.json
```